# Live boot cannot see hard drives

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I used Yumi to install multiboot for Ubuntu and Mint live.

On the same external hard drive I have a separate ext4 partition, which I would like to do a full install of Linux on.

When I got to install, I cannot see any hard drives in the list.  However when I go to gparted I can see my partition fine. It's mounted to the media.

If I click the change button the installer crashes. (The same thing happens for mint, however atleast mint pops up the error that's occuring)

> argument of type nonetype is not iterable

Note: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 amd desktop iso

How can I install Ubuntu on the same drive I'm booting live from?

Comment: Yes you can install Ubuntu to the same drive you are using; an different partition to anything in use though. You haven't mentioned OS/release details so this is generic advice  (Ubuntu is available using at least four different installers... I don't know if it applies to all for example).

Comment: Thanks I'll add an update with more info

Comment: If you are able to boot `toram` you can install to the same partition you are booting from. Unmount the partition after booting. If booting a YUMI USB press `e` at the grub menu and type a space and `toram` after `--` on the `linux` line. If booting Syslinux, press `SHIFT` when booting, `ESC` at the language screen then press `F6` then `ESC` again then type a space and `toram`

Comment: @C.S.Cameron, I already have two seperate partitions on the drive, but if I can't get it to work using the free partition, Ill merge partitions back and try toram